# Running .NET app from network share in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, .net

We have a .NET 1.1 application that we keep on a netowork share.  We install the .NET Framerwork to the local PCs and also set the full trust via the following:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\caspol -pp off -cg LocalIntranet_Zone FullTrust

This has worked fine on all PCs to date however now we have a few new PCs with Win7 and the process no longer is working.  The app will run fine from a local drive in Win7 but running the networked copy results in a general exception error.

Any ideas on how to get this to work under Win7?

Comment: Have you tried less restrictive UAC settings, or turning UAC off?

Comment: UAC is set to never notify.

Comment: If you run caspol.exe -rsg \\server\share\app.exe what zone is it appearing in?

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure.  Caspol can require some tinkering to get it right.  Just a hunch:  if this is x64 Windows 7, try running caspol from the Framework64 folder.

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v1.1.4322\caspol.exe -m -ag 1 -url "file:////\\computername\sharename\*" FullTrust -exclusive on

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the command prompt you run caspol from is launched with "Run As Administrator".

Just being in the Administrators group is not enough, you need the above to bypass UAC.